# Check if map key greater than value

Tags: java, android

I want to make buildAlertMessageVersion() execute only when the value of child "version" is higher than 1.5

Here is the example I used but it only works if it's equals to 1.5

```java
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
        Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        if(map.get("version").equals(1.5)){
            buildAlertMessageVersion();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What subclass of Object  is keyed to "version"? I would expect it to be a String, not a Double. For example, it might be "1.5.2" which could not be represented as a double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`if(map.get("version").equals(1.5))` to `if(map.get("version") > 1.5)`

Comment: operator '>' can not be applied to 'java.lang.object', 'double'

Comment: you can cast it to double -> ((double)(map.get("version")) > 1.5)